# Big cap notation in probability

Tags: probability, notation

Let $X_i$ be a random variable. Is the following true?

$$P\left\{\bigcap^k_{i=1}(X_i < 0)\right\} \equiv P\left\{(X_1 < 0) \land (X_2 < 0) \land \dots \land (X_k < 0) \right\}$$

or does the "big cap" notation mean something different in a probability context?

Comment: it is true. ........

Comment: In practice $\cap$ is used, not $\wedge$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two "events" $E$ and $F$, set-theoretic intersection $E\cap F$ and boolean algebra conjunction $E\wedge F$ means the same thing.

Although, in the [foundation of probability theory](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/275a-notes-0-foundations-of-probability-theory), people may want to distinguish events from models of events.